# Apache set custom header with an evironment variable

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I'm trying to return custom header with value GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE from Maxmind module.

I've tried the following and nothing works

```
# MaxMind Requirements:
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPScanProxyHeaders On
Header set anchorglobal-country-test "%{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}e"
Header set anchorglobal-country "%{GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}e"
```

Please advise what's missing.

Thanks.

Comment: GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE  should be env variable, so you might need to set it first with SetEnv directive before setting the header "SetEnv MyGEOCODE %{GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE}" Header set anchorglobal-country "%{MyGEOCODE}e"

Comment: also worth doublechecking- did the geoip service start successfully after installing it and restarting apache? [be sure you're running the right version for your Apache install too:  https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2/ ]

Comment: @AnsonWHan I can confirm that the module is installed properly as I have other sites with geo ip detection working properly.

My only problem now is to get the country code returned as HTTP response header.

Comment: @DanilaLadner I tried your suggestion and I got %{GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} printed as the header value.