# Apache Custom Header with an environment variable

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers, environment-variables

I try to set a custom HTTP Header with an environment variable** with Apache server 2.4.6 and headers_module.

I work inside a HTTP VHost on port 80.

Everything work as expected with basic example like:

`Header set MyHeader "%D %t"`

I have read the Apache Documentation of mod_headers : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_headers.html#header

It is said that one can access environment variable using
`%{ENVVARNAME}e`

*(with ENVVARNAME the name of the ENV variable)*

I also read other post but no real working answer:
[Apache set custom header with an evironment variable](https://serverfault.com/questions/886119/apache-set-custom-header-with-an-evironment-variable)

But my problem is to add a header than identify my Apache Server like the HOSTNAME environment value

1. I tried this

`Header Set X-Serv %{HOSTNAME}e`

No success : always display X-Serv:{null} instead of the value

2. I also tried :

`SetEnv myvar ${HOSTNAME}
Header set X-Serv %{myvar}e`

No success : it displays in my HTTP Headers : X-Serv: %{myvar}e

I also tried some other various combinations:

Please note: My HOSTNAME environment variable exists and it display in 'env' command with the apache user owning the httpd process

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

You have to declare which system environment variables you want to be usable with the [`PassEnv` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#passenv)

A working example would be:

```
PassEnv HOSTNAME
Header Set X-Serv %{HOSTNAME}e
```

Answer (score 4):

Found a way to get it working:

- Ensure module is activated (mod_headers) or activate if necessary

  ```
  a2enmod headers
  ```
- in /etc/apache2/envvars add

  ```
  export HOSTNAME=`uname -n`
  ```
- in `<VirtualHost>` clause

  ```
  Header set apachehost ${HOSTNAME}
  ```
- Restart or reload httpd service

  ```
  service apache2 restart
  ```

Answer (score 4):

1.Ensure module is activated (mod_headers) or activate if necessary

`a2enmod headers`

2.in /etc/apache2/envvars add

`` export HOSTNAME1=`uname -n` ``  or `` `hostname` ``

3.in `<VirtualHost _default:443>` clause

`PassEnv HOSTNAME1`

`Header set X-Server "%{HOSTNAME1}e"`

4.Restart or reload httpd service

`service apache2 restart`